# converting a div element into inline in css

Tags: html, css

Hello friends i have a problem in a css i want to convert a div tag into inline

```
<div id="menu1">
 <ul>
 <a href="#"> <li>  one</li> </a>
 <a href="#"> <li>  two</li> </a>
 <a href="#"> <li>  three</li> </a>
 <a href="#"> <li> four </li> </a>
 <a href="#"> <li> five</li> </a>
 <a href="#"> <li>six </li> </a>
 <a href="#"> <li> seven </li> </a>
 <a href="#"> <li> eight </li> </a>
 </ul>
 </div>

<div id="menu2">
<ul>
<a href="#"> <li>  one</li> </a>
<a href="#"> <li>  two</li> </a>
<a href="#"> <li>  three</li> </a>
<a href="#"> <li> four </li> </a>
<a href="#"> <li> five</li> </a>
<a href="#"> <li>six </li> </a>
<a href="#"> <li> seven </li> </a>
<a href="#"> <li> eight </li> </a>
</ul>
</div>
```

now i want that a menu 1 display on,left side and menu 2 display on right side iam using display inline but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
div {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qTY3h/6/).

Or, if your users have a compliant browser, you can set the `width` to `50%`, using `box-sizing` to contain the `padding` and `border-width` within the defined `width` of the element:

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qTY3h/5/).

Similarly, given compliant browsers, you could instead use the `column-count` property to define a specific number of columns, into which the browser will fit the content. For this to work I've wrapped your current (hideously invalid) html in another element, with an `id` of 'wrapper':

```
#wrapper {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -ms-column-count: 2;
    -o-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qTY3h/4/).

If you have the option of only requiring Webkit and Opera support, and perhaps your users have enabled flex-box support in their Firefox installation, then using the CSS flex-box model becomes an option, though again requires a wrapping element to contain the two menu elements, with the following CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#wrapper > div {
    display: -webkit-flex-inline;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qTY3h/7/).

> Note: WebKit implementation must be prefixed with `-webkit`; Gecko implementation is unprefixed but behind a preference (except if you are using Nightly); Internet Explorer implements an old version of the spec, prefixed; Opera 12.10 implements the latest version of the spec, unprefixed.

---

#### The invalid mark-up

```
<div id="menu1">
 <ul>
       <a href="#"> <li>  one</li> </a>
       <a href="#"> <li>  two</li> </a>
       <a href="#"> <li>  three</li> </a>
       <a href="#"> <li> four </li> </a>
       <a href="#"> <li> five</li> </a>
       <a href="#"> <li>six </li> </a>
       <a href="#"> <li> seven </li> </a>
       <a href="#"> <li> eight </li> </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The *only* valid child element of a `ul` (or an `ol`) is an `li`: no other elements are permitted within a `ul` or `ol` *unless* they're wrapped in an `li` element. So, to correct your HTML, it should be:

```
<div id="menu1">
 <ul>
       <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">six</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">seven</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">eight</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If the purpose of wrapping the `li` with an `a` was to make the clickable area of the `a` element fill the `li`, then simply use `a { display: block; }`

References:

- [CSS Flexbox Please! (Flexbox playground/demo)](http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/).
- [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module (W3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float).
- ['Using CSS Flexible Boxes' (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Comment: but in both ways answer is same either <li> inside <a> or <a> inside <li> please tell me what are the benifits of <a> inside <li>

Comment: Browsers will attempt to rescue broken/invalid HTML; if you supply valid HTML the browser doesn't (unpredictably) rearrange the mark-up when it's forming the DOM, which means it's easier to work with. The reason not to wrap the `li` with an `a` is simply that *it is* ***invalid*** HTML. The question becomes, then, why would you *not* want to write your HTML properly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try [`float: left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float) for the 2 `<div>`s?

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkZ6e/)**.

```css
#menu1, #menu2 {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the CSS `float` attribute you can attain what you are looking for.

```
#menu1 {
    float: left;
}
#menu2 {
    float: left;
}
```

You can look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tB9kq/1/) as an example.

#### See Also

- [CSS-Tricks - All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)
- [W3Schools - CSS Float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should displayed your lists in inline-block (with inline-block you keep the initial width).

```
#menu1, #menu2 {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Olivier